# R how to extract quarterly dates from a dataframe

Tags: r, lubridate, data-wrangling

From the given dataframe i would like to extract quarterly months.

```
Category = c("New", "New","New","New","Old","Old","Old","Old",
"Expired","Expired", "Expired","Expired")
Date_Monthly   =c("Jan-2014", "Feb-2014", "Mar-2014", "Apr-2014", "May-2014", 
"Jun-2014", "Jul-2014", "Aug-2014", "Sep-2014","Oct-2014","Nov-2014","Dec-2014")
Monthly_Vals =   c(4,7,6,7,8,12,10,11,10,16,12,120)
```

```
df1 <- data.frame(Category, Date_Monthly,Monthly_Vals)
```

I have tired with lubridate but i get the
Error
`Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)):character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

```
lubridate::quarter(df1$Date_Monthly)
```

Is there any other way to extract quarterly dates data from the dataframe ?

**Expected Outcome**

```
  Category   Date_Monthly   Monthly_Vals
   New        Mar-2014        6
   Old        Jun-2014        12
   Expired    Sep-2014       10
   Expired    Dec-2014       120
```

Comment: `subset(df1, grepl("Mar|Jun|Sep|Dec", Date_Monthly))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the month-year values into daate, you can use `lubridate::my` and then you can extract the month and subset the the values you want. For example

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(lubridate::month(lubridate::my(Date_Monthly)) %in% c(3,6,9,12))
#   Category Date_Monthly Monthly_Vals
# 1      New     Mar-2014            6
# 2      Old     Jun-2014           12
# 3  Expired     Sep-2014           10
# 4  Expired     Dec-2014          120
```

Comment: thanks it worked, within that filter can i also rename the columns `Date_Monthly` to `Date_Quarterly` and `Monthly_Vals` to `Quartly_Val` ?

Comment: A filter doesn't allow you to rename. The `dplyr` library as a `rename()` function you can use to rename columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` and `filter`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    separate(Date_Monthly   , into = c("month", "year"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>% 
    filter(month %in% month.abb[seq(3,12,3)]) %>% 
    select(-month, -year)

  Category Date_Monthly Monthly_Vals
1      New     Mar-2014            6
2      Old     Jun-2014           12
3  Expired     Sep-2014           10
4  Expired     Dec-2014          120
```